# How can I have Beamer number slides in a frame title?

Tags: beamer, counters

More or less what it says on the tin: I want something like:

```
\frame{\somecounterforpagenumbers : My Title}
```

I assume there is a built in counter that I can reference here, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: The counter you are looking for is `framenumber`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the command `\insertframenumber`, the corresponding counter is called `framenumber`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
% manually increase the frame number
\setcounter{framenumber}{23}
% display frame number in the frame title
\begin{frame}{\insertframenumber{}: First frame, or is it?}
Some text here\dots
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep, that seems to be it. Might be worth updating to incorporate Corentin's comment, since the counter itself is called framenumber, in case one wants to manipulate its state. Thanks!

Comment: Please see my updated answer!